# how to pass TADOConnection object to Delphi Dll from c# .net

Tags: c#, delphi

I have a Delphi function with Declaration as:

```pascal
DFunction(inp1:string; AppHandle: THandle; Conn: _Connection):string;stdCall;
```

where `_Connection` is of type `Winapi.ADIInt._Connection`.

How do I call this function passing the connection object. And what exactly is the `AppHandle` - do I need to pass that as well from C# code?

Comment: AppHandle could be anything. Read the documentation for the DLL. The first parameter is a Delphi string. You can't make one of those in your C# code. _Connection probably can't be readily made in your C# code either. Your expectations are probably grossly unrealistic. Likely you can't expect to call this function from C# and any solution or workaround is going to involve a lot of learning.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ADO is COM based, so it is *possible* for C# to pass in a standard ADO `Connection` object. But .NET has its own ADO wrapper, that probably is not compatible.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan and Remy. So if I ask Delphi team to take connectionString instead of expecting an object, they should be able to create connection. I was checking out for Application Handle for .net: Should passing UIntPtr suffice this reqmt.

Comment: Yes it's a UIntPtr, but the unknown is what value you are expected to pass